# Find right triangle vertex by 2 vertex, hypotenuse and angles

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, 3d

Trying to solve this problem for 3D.
Please, see triangle below.

1. **A** and **C** are known vertices - **A**(x1, y1, z1) and **C**(x1, y1, z3)
2. Angle **ACB** is right angle, others are known
3. Distances **AB** and **AC** are known too
4. x and y coordinates are the same for **A** and **B**
5. z coordinate is the same for **B** and **C**
6. We need to find vertex **B**(x2, y2, z3)

I will appreciate for any help!

[Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBFS5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not unique.

$$(x_1+a\cos \theta, y_1+a\sin \theta,z_3)$$

is a solution for any $\theta$, where $a=\sqrt{c^2-b^2}$ is known.

[image]

Comment: Is _θ_ **ABC** angle?

Comment: Angle $ABC$ is always the same no matter where $B$ is on the circle

Comment: In fact, all triangles are congruent no matter where $B$ is on the circle

Comment: If angle $ABC$ as I have shown here is not equal to the one specified, then there is no solution